# Trigger to replace character following insert

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

Is it possible to create a trigger for a certain user which replaces a character just after loading data into any table?

For example, I need to replace all '1' s with '9' s in PERS_ID column  when a user loads data into a table.

I am complete newbie to PLSQL, so I don't know even where to start.

I'm not sure if I could make clear about my goal, so please feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, you certainly can... (For simplicity, I'm assuming that `pers_id` is a string rather than a number-- if it is a number, you could, of course, convert it to a string, run the `replace` and convert it back to a number in the trigger)

```
SQL> create table foo( pers_id varchar2(10) );

Table created.

SQL> create trigger replace_data
  2    before insert on foo
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.pers_id := replace( :new.pers_id, '1', '9' );
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into foo values( '123abc456' );

1 row created.

SQL> select * from foo;

PERS_ID
----------
923abc456
```

Practically, however, the requirement seems exceptionally odd.  Having a trigger silently change the data that is being inserted is generally a bad idea because it tends to make debugging exceptionally difficult.  Future developers are very likely to be rather surprised when the data they they inserted into the table doesn't match the data that they see when they query the table and they are unlikely to immediately figure out that a trigger changed the data.  If you can describe the business problem that you are trying to solve, we can likely come up with a more appropriate technical solution.